# Add elements to existing plotly plot in R

Tags: r, plotly

I'm just starting to use plotly and I haven't been able to do something as simple as adding objects to an existing plot. How can I add line segments to an existing empty plot?

I've tried this, but every call of `add_segment` creates a new plot with only one segment:

```
p<-plot_ly()
add_segment(p,x=0,y=1,x=5,y=1)
add_segment(p,x=0,y=4,x=5,y=4)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer:** use the **`%>%`** operator like this:

```
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x)
p <- p %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0',mode = 'lines')
p
```

**The details:**

One approach is to use the piping `%>%` operator from [this example](https://plot.ly/r/line-charts/) where the following plot is produced by the code below:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)
trace_0 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = -5)
x <- c(1:100)

data <- data.frame(x, trace_0, trace_1, trace_2)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0',mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', mode = 'lines+markers') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~trace_2, name = 'trace 2', mode = 'markers')
p
```

**Step by step using `%>%`:**

**Code Step 1:**

```
# step 1
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x)

# plot
p
```

**Plot step 1:**

[image]

**Code step 2:**

```
# step 1
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x)

# step 2
p <- p %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0',mode = 'lines')

# plot
p
```

**Plot step 2:**

[image]

**Code all steps:**

```
# step 1
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x)

# step 2
p <- p %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0',mode = 'lines')

# step 3
p <- p %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', mode = 'lines+markers')

# step 4
p <- p %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_2, name = 'trace 2', mode = 'markers')

# plot
p
```

**Plot all steps:**

[image]

**Edit:** Response to comments

> Is there any way to add elements without using the pipe?

Not to my knowledge, but I'm hoping someone proves me wrong. Since this is an `[R]` question, I'm guessing you're more familiar with building ggplot plots stepwise like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, color=cut)) + geom_point()
g <- g + geom_smooth()
g
```

The `+` approach will not work for plotly though:

**Code:**

```
# step 1
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x)

# step 2
p <- p + add_trace(y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0',mode = 'lines')
```

**Error:**

> Error in add_data(p, data) : argument "p" is missing, with no default

And there's absolutely no reason to fear the `%>%` operator. `a %>% b` simply means something along the lines of `Take a, and do b with it`. To my knowledge, this was first seen in the [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package, and is widely used in the fantastic [dplyr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8) package. I'm mostly messing around with python at the time, but this ***really*** makes me miss `R`

Comment: I don't understand very well what's the difference, technically the pipe operator shouldn't make `function(x)` the same as `x %>% function()`?

I'm gonna try with add_trace instead to check, thanks!

Comment: Only on phone right now, but I'll check back in tomorrow for some more details.

Comment: try: p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x)

Comment: and then: p %>%
  add_trace(y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0',mode = 'lines')

Comment: Is there any way to add elements without using the pipe?

Comment: Plotly should take into account your group_by() statement in your data (if using a dataframe).  Also, you can add additional elements through the color, linetype, and markertype arguments.

Comment: Well, i'm marking your answer as the accepted because it's a clear explaining even if it doesn't helped the point of adding of elements without using the pipe. I don't use `ggplot` or `plotly` since i think they are really bad libraries, everything in my opinion should be done using `baseplot`, which i do. The issue i'm facing (that's why i'm trying to learn plotly) is the static image plotting of baseplot, which is giving me some really slow-run code in a very specific shiny project due to the specific features of it. Thanks in advance!